# django added a new class in a model

Tags: django, model, django-south

This thing never happened to me before,as i never had to create another class in the model field after doing syncdb already. I am now reviewing one of my past projects and i need to add another class in the models.py file. I have very little understanding of south, its more like a procedural one.

when i do this

```
 ./manage.py sql app_name
```

it showls the new table but when i run the server it throws an operational error 'no such table found'. Am i missing something this whole time?? Is there a way??

Answer (score 1):

according to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sql)

```
./manage.py sql app_name
```

just print sql statement for create table.
you can write it in a file

```
./manage.py sql app_name > command.sql
```

and feed it to database. for example if use postgresql you can use:

```
psql -U user db_name < command.sql
```